# Cómo hago para cuando escriba en un jTextfield me separe los números por Centésimas?

Tags: java

Quiero  hacer que cuando escriba o cuando envié un valor al `jTextField` me los separe por sentécimas , Ejm

> 150.645.000

lo estuve intentando con `DecimalFormat` pero no logro que me salga en el `jTextField`

Este es mi código

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Vista.Manejador.abrirpantallacompras();


   DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###");
   Vista.Compras.txtprecio.setText(df.format(15000));

}
```

Con este código envió al `jTextField` pero no se como hacer para que al escribirlos me los separe por sentécimas.

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? ¿Cúal es tu código?

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vista.Manejador.abrirpantallacompras();
        
        
       DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("#,###,###,###");
       Vista.Compras.txtprecio.setText(df.format(15000));
          
} con este codigo envio al jTextField pero no se como  hacer para cuando escriba  los numeros me los separe de igual  forma

Comment: bueno seria que cuando digitara el numero en el jTexField quedara 15.000  o el numero que digitara solo que me los separara por sentecimas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que desea es que al escribir se aplique el formato deseado , podría utilizar otro elemento diferente a `JTextField` que sería [JFormattedTextField](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) y se le añade una máscara de la siguiente forma. *(el formato ya se podría modificar según como desee mostrar los datos)*

```
JFormattedTextField txtformateado = new JFormattedTextField();
txtformateado.setFormatterFactory(
         new DefaultFormatterFactory(new MaskFormatter("#,###,###,###")));
```

Comment: Gracias lo intentare de esa forma

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es sencilla, ya casi lo tenías. El problema esta en el formato que estas definiendo en el constructor de `DecimalFormat()`.

Los 3 `#` que están después de la primera coma definen cada cuantos digitos se insertará el punto. Por ejemplo:

```
#,#         #,##      #,###
1.0.0.0     1.00.0    1.000
1.0.0.0.0   10.00.0   10.000
```

Para lo que quieres el formato correcto es `#,###`.

```
DecimalFormat df=new DecimalFormat("#,###");
Vista.Compras.txtprecio.setText(df.format(15000));
```

Comment: gracias lo tendre en cuenta pues en le formato que estaba usando me funcionaba me los separaba pero solo cuando envio el valor asi como se muestra en el codigo,  el problema es que no se como  hacer para cuando escriba en el  jTextField me los separe tambien.